# trying to delete values from linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to remove a specific node from the list but somehow this code is not working. I have a counter to keep track of the index where the list is at now. and if the count and in index I want to delete is the same, it is suppose to delete.

ps: i am not suppose to use the link list api.

```
    public void doRemove(int index, int size) {
            // implementation

            int listCount =1;

            ListNode temp = head;
            ListNode previous = head;

            while (temp.getNext() != null)
            {

            listCount++;


                    previous = temp;
                    temp = temp.getNext();
                    if ( listCount == index) 
                    {
                    previous.setNext(temp);
                    temp.setNext(temp.getNext());
                    }
            }



            }
```

Comment: What's not working? Please explain what exactly doesn't.

Comment: the node wasnt removed.

Comment: @user2760642: Try to provide a [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: change previous.setNext(temp) to previous.setNext(temp.getNext())

Comment: Are you sure, your getNext() and setNext() are working fine? because there isn't any problem with the logic of your code mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( listCount == index) 
{
   previous.setNext(temp.getNext());
 }
```

Try using this. This is assuming that its a singly-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
public void doRemove(int index, int size) {


        int listCount =1;

        ListNode temp = head;
        ListNode previous = head;

        for(int i=0;temp.getnext()!=null;i++)
        {
           listCount++;

                if(!(listCount == index))
               {
                   previous = temp;
                   temp = temp.getNext();
               } 
                else
               {
                  previous.setNext(temp.getNext());
               }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing the node:

Use this: `previous.setNext(temp.getNext());`

```
prev -> temp -> temp.next
```

If you want to remove `temp`, then use above line.

Comment: just wanted to confirm, if he doesn't add this line, would **previous** not be following **temp** automatically, skipping the node to be removed, soon after the next iteration starts?

Comment: yes according to his code previous follows temp on every iteration but when he encounters a node to be deleted he re-assigns the node to be pointed by previous and that's why the node is never deleted.

Comment: @MaheshGosemath when temp reaches at the node which is required to be deleted, he does: prev = temp, and temp = temp->next. which means, he simply skips the node to be deleted. and on very next iteration, prev again starts following temp. which MUST not cause any problem. Am i missing something?

Comment: what he is doing on every iteration is temp is a step ahead of previous i.e. temp = previous.next. Now when the node is encountered what he is doing is previous.next = temp which is same as earlier. Even if he swap the statements in his if block that will do.